# Binary Search Tree Insert Problems (Java)

Tags: java, insert, binary-search-tree

So I have a setup program reading in country records from a file and my goal is to make an   index based on the 3 char letter representation of a country (ex. USA).  I am required to   use 6 Parallel arrays.  LeftChPtr, 3 char Arrays for the Code, DataRecPtr, and RightChPtr.

Here is the method InsertCode it is being sent in the DataRecPtr and the 3 chars in an array.

After all the data is inserted, It is saved to a file and when I look at the file I can tell it's wrong because the pointers aren't correct.

Please help, I am in no way asking you to write code for me I just don't see the problem.
    Thanks

```
N = 0
rootPtr = -1
parentI = 0;


    public void InsertCode(short ID, char[] cc)
            {
                drp = ID;
                short i;
                codeArray1[N] = cc[0];
                codeArray2[N] = cc[1];
                codeArray3[N] = cc[2];
                leftChPtr[N] = -1;
                rightChPtr[N] = -1;
                dataRecPtr[N] = drp;

                if (rootPtr == -1)   //special case - no nodes in BST yet
                    rootPtr = N;
                else //normal case 
                {
                    i = rootPtr;
                    String dataN = "";
                    dataN += codeArray1[N] + codeArray2[N] + codeArray1[N];

                    while (i != -1)
                    {   parentI = i;
                        String dataI = "";
                        dataI += codeArray1[i] + codeArray2[i] + codeArray3[i];

                        if (dataN.compareTo(dataI) < 0)
                        {
                            i = leftChPtr[i];
                            LorR = true;//L
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            i = rightChPtr[i];
                            LorR = false;//R
                        }
                    }                 
                    //i++;?????????????????

                if (LorR == true)
                    leftChPtr[parentI] = N;
                else 
                    rightChPtr[parentI] = N;
                }
                N++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant see anything wrong with the insert method apart from LorR should be declared. May be you should check the code for saving into a file.